# how to create a warning if there's an existing rows in database using c# in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#

As you can see in my name, I'm just a beginner...

I'm trying to make a system where in anyone can register, but, it will not allow someone to register once the unique data already exists.. (e.g UserID, emails, Username etc..)

is there any code of it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Read this page first please before asking a new question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @S.Akbari Thank you! Mr. Do you know how to deny a request if someone is trying to enter an existing Unique Data?

Comment: If you're asking this kind of question, then you should probably go back to basics. 1) get the input username, 2) check the database for said username, 3) if it exists then let the user know and prompt them to choose a different name

Comment: Thank you for the feedbacks, Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the vagueness of the question and the fact they're not actually saying that "this isn't working", I'm going to give dummy code in C#.

```
public bool CheckUserExists(string inputUserId)
{
    var existingUser = GetUserFromDatabase(inputUserId);

    if (existingUser == null)
    {
        return false; // The user doesn't exist
    }
    else
    {
        return true; // The user does exist already
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedbacks and answer, it does really worked!